# Blocking Thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

here's my problem: I have an application that launches a simulated server locally. The output of this operation is redirected to a log file and I want to look for a specific pattern in this log file while it's being written.

I already implemented the tail -f simulation (I have to work on windows), but I can't get the two threads to work fine simultaneously.

Here's a sample (in the main) :

```
server.launch();
patternFinder.start();
```

The patternFinder extends Thread and here is what its run method looks like:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        //tail -f implementation

        //I'll set a timeout when I can get it 
        //to work (the pattern is supposed to be found)
    }
}
```

If I put `patternFinder.join()` after the `start()`, the server will pause its execution and wait for the patternFinder to return (but he won't because nothing is being written in the log). But the child thread need to block the main thread because we don't want any instruction to be executed until the pattern is found (or the timeout limit has been reached).

Any ideas?

(ps: first post so don't hesitate to tell me if I did something wrong or if you need any more details)

Comment: Does server.launch() create a new thread ? I'm confused what's going on conceptually. What is waiting for what from which thread ?

Comment: no the server.launch() is executed in the main thread, but it's just executing a java command with Runtime.exec(), so it's not waiting for the server to be started. That's why I need a patternFinder, to make sure it started correctly.

Comment: So why does patternFinder.join() not work ? Presumably the server is already running after the Runtime.exec call. The main thread blocking shouldn't affect the server.

Comment: Well I just checked and it is a ProcessBuilder.start and not Runtime.exec, I know it's not supposed to change anything to my problem but just to be accurate. You're right that's really weird, the server.start works just fine if I don't start the patternFinder thread.

Comment: Why would patternFind.join() block the server from running when it has been kicked off and is running in a completely separate process ?

Comment: And if I manually stop the patternFinder thread, the server.start() continues its execution and write in the log.

Comment: You mention "I already implemented the tail -f simulation (I have to work on windows)" but if your goal is simply to produce tail -f functionality why not install Cywgin and then you can run tail -f rather than having to code anything in Java?

Comment: Because it has to be run in our solution test suite. Theses tests have to be automated.

Comment: Generate thread stack trace and try to find out what `main` thread is doing. You can use `<ctrl> + <break>` shortcut to generate that trace: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

Comment: Are you breaking your `while(true)` loop when pattern is found? Are you positive that you actually find that pattern? May be you should put some print statement or a breakpoint inside the loop to see what's going on for sure.

Comment: Yes I do break the `while(true)` and for test purpose I know for sure that the pattern has to be found. As I said the real problem is that main thread is "pausing" its execution when I start the patternFinder thread, so nothing is being written in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this questioned doesn't stay unanswered I found some kind of a workaround but never figured what was really the problem.

So apparently the problem was that I was launching my server via a ProcessBuilder with a command looking like this `java [arguments] [classpath] fileToLaunch`. I tried a lot of things but the only one that worked was to change the command to `cmd /C start java [arguments] [classpath] fileToLaunch` so it starts the server in a new window and then everything worked as expected.

If ever someone can explain that mystery to me, feel free to provide a new answer that still could be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Events to coordinate your threads. You can wait on an event in the main thread and set/reset it on your child thread when things have been found.

You can use Manual or AutoResetEvents for that.  Not sure what they are called in Java, but I'm sure you can find that out.

Comment: I don't think that's appropriate for Java.